# Python Selenium - How to click on Load More dynamically till it disappers?

Tags: python, selenium

I am going through a site and the site has a Load More button which I need to click on until it no more appears on the site, I have written the below code but not sure if there is a better way to handle than a WHILE loop. Are there other selenium methods to handle this?

```
driver.get(url)
while driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath").is_displayed():
    try:
        loadmore = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath")
        loadmore.click()
    except Exception as e:
        break
```

this works but I get 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_displayed' after its done with all the clicking, I wrote another code

```
while True:  
    try:
        loadmore = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//xpath")
        loadmore.click()
    except Exception as e:
        break
```

this works without errors as the exception is caught since I dont use the is_displayed method.

Comment: I think your second snippet is the ideal way. Only concern I can see is if the "load more" changes to different text while loading, and then reverts back to "load more" but I am not sure if that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) with `expected_conditions`, i.e.:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('theurl')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) # increase the timeout as needed
el = wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//xpath")))
el.click()
```

Comment: Yes I am planning to use Wait just like your code but with your code, the load more button will only be clicked once so I am adding the wait code inside the while loop.